# Is there any of Special way of showing Tentative Tasks in a Gantt graph using Project Libre?

Tags: pm-software, scheduling, gantt, task-management

I'm documenting a Software Web Application Project Plan. The customers have sent us:

1) snapshots of the various Web pages, and

2) Change Request Snapshots of some existing Web pages that we already developed.

Also, they send us software functional requirements through various emails. In other words, the software functional reqs are scattered here and there in various emails.

I started writing a Software Web Application Project Plan for the Webpages that so far contains various tasks that pertain to changes in aesthetics, and content of the webpages.

I created a Gantt graph using Project Libre. I listed out the various Tasks, Subtasks, work packages, etc., but is there any of showing Tentative Tasks? In other words, is there a way to ensure that other people who review the Gantt graph know that it is a tentative task?

The reason I'm asking is that the Customer is constantly changing requirements which is quite common in software projects.

Comment: What causes a "Tentative Task" in your project plan? Is the requirement not clear? Do you think it might change? Are you not able to estimate the duration making the end date tentative? Users here may be able to offer some solutions if you can provide more detail on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If by "tentative" task you mean one that is not approved or unclear whether it will be in the scope, it generally shouldn't be in the project plan. It should rather be relegated to another document.

Anyway, if you have to do it: In MS Project, you'd be able to color-code the task name or the duration bar in the Gantt chart. This would make tentative tasks very easily distinguishable.

Projectlibre doesn't allow color coding unfortunately, so the only other way I can think of, is to add an extra column to your Gantt.

You do this by right-clicking one of the existing column names and selecting "Insert column". As "Field" you can just specify "Flag 1". This will give you a column with a checkbox for each row / task.

You can then rename the column (just right click the newly created column) to "Tentative" and set a checkmark for every tentative task. This will then be shown in the Gantt chart.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to write the same explanation as @MortenK, but still can append on his answer.

After you have done as Morten described above regarding a "Flag 1" column and you want to be able to toggle visibility by using the `Show (I guess it is called) > Filter dropdown menu (for Flag 1)` you will see that you will only filter the ones that are checked as Tentative.

Unfortunately I don't think you can inverse the filter, i.e. "NOT Flag 1" and therefore you would have to Flag the `Regular` instead of the Tentative to be able to toggle between `No filter` (all tasks, regular and tentative) and `Flag 1`.

(Alternative, have two flags if you want to be able to filter both regular tasks and tentative tasks separately.)